# Omitting/filtering dirs from find output

Tags: find, directory, rm

`find /home/alex/devops/backups/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +60`

Outputs :

```
/home/alex/devops/backups/
/home/alex/devops/backups/R8.1
/home/alex/devops/backups/R11.0
/home/alex/devops/backups/R.16.2.1
```

How can I exclude the `/home/alex/devops/backups/` from find output ?

I am asking this because the purpose is to remove all the dirs that find outputs ( `find /home/alex/devops/backups -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +60 -exec rm -rf {} \`) and at this stage actually I delete the whole `/home/alex/devops/backups/` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `-maxdepth 1`, so most likely your `find` will also understand `-mindepth 1`. This test will not match `/home/alex/devops/backups/` which (as a starting-point) is considered to be at depth `0`.

```
find /home/alex/devops/backups/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +60
```